# Issues using custom iOS UITableView cells / "Multiple segues with identifier" error

Tags: uitableview, ios5, xcode4.2, uistoryboard

I have created a Table View that has multiple Table View Cells of different styles - say "CellStyle1" and "CellStyle2".

The cells look different, but they should perform the same when selected - namely, segueing to the same new view.

I have set up both cells to have the same Storyboard Segue - "PushView", pointing to the same view controller.

This seems to work OK, but Xcode generates a warning: "Multiple segues with identifier"

How can I avoid this error?  What is the right way to handle multiple custom cells that look differently but act the same and should segue to the same place?

This one has me scratching my head.

Thanks!

Comment: This post <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763529/perform-a-segue-called-by-a-uitableviewcell> helps me

Answer (score 4):

You could make one segue by ctrl dragging from the view controller to  the destination view controller. And then assuming tapping the cell is the event that you want to trigger the segue, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath call performSegueWithIdentifier.

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

Or just give the 2 segues different identifiers and in prepereForSegue check for either identifier.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I have a UITableViewcontroller and when a cell is selected I want to either go to 1 destination view or a different one. It seems that I cant assign more than one segue to a table cell?

Comment: That is correct, so you want to make the segue 'generic' and ctrl drag from the viewController icon at the bottom. Then in tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath: determine which segue to perform.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. When you say generic is that a property that needs to be set?

Comment: no, it is just a term I made up to mean the segue isn't triggered by anything. Try the Stanford CS193p videos on iTunes he explains Storyboard.

Comment: Thanks! This worked really well for me. The key is dragging from the view controller not the table view cell