# Perform a Segue Called by a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, action, segue

I have some UIButtons in a custom table view cell that when pressed I want them to call segues in the view controller that is host to the table view that the cells are in. What I am doing now is declaring an action like this:
    - (void)action;

in the class that the table view is in. And then I am calling that action from the cell like this:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[viewController action];
```

However when the action is called it says that there is no such segue for the view controller which I know to be incorrect. Calling "action" from the view controller itself works perfectly, just not from the cell.

Also, here is the code to perform the segue:

```
-(void)action {
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"action" sender:self];
}
```

How can I make this work?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

I just tried to set a delegate on the cell like this:

Cell's header file:
    @class PostCellView;

```
@protocol PostCellViewDelegate
-(void)action;
@end

@interface PostCellView : UITableViewCell <UIAlertViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <PostCellViewDelegate> delegate;
```

And in the main file for the cell I call the action like this:
    [self.delegate action];

and in the header for the view that hosts the Table View I import the cell like this:
    #import "PostCellView.h"

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, PostCellViewDelegate>
```

Then in the main file for that view I have the cells action:

```
-(void)action {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"action" sender:self];

}
```

But the action is never performed, I checked. I logged when I call the action from the cell and I put an NSLog on the action itself and the log for calling it from the cell worked but not the action.

Comment: Can you show the code where you perform the segue?

Comment: Is allocating and initializing the view controller just an example? I don't see why you would have to do that, since the TableViewController already exists when the cell's button is tapped.

Comment: No, it wasn't but I realized when another user pointed out that I should add the cell as a delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with this `ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[viewController action];`
You are initiating a new ViewController and not getting the current one the cell is in.

Maybe you can set a delegate on the cell so the cell has a reference to the viewController

Comment: I just tried to add the cell as a delegate but I couldn't get it to work, I added my code and the problem I am having to the original question.

Comment: In cellForRowAtIndexPath did you set cell.delegate=self?

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach to create a button and call its handler programatically is

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 80, 40)];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:button]; //self.view is the view on which you want to add button
```

and its handler should be defined like this in your implementation file:

```
-(void)buttonClick:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"button clicked");
    // your code on click of button 
}
```

You can check [iOS documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html).

Hope this will help you to find out your problem. :)

Comment: That is not at all what I was asking... I need to have a button in a custom UITableViewCell, which I have already setup to an IBAction in the cell, call an action to perform a segue in the view controller that the UITableView is in.

Comment: have you seen this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html  may be this will help you.

Comment: I don't need to create a custom segue, I just need to call a segue that is setup to a view controller from a custom UITableViewCell.